# Alternative for showModalDialog in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Is there anyway to open a **synchronous** popup window that works in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: window.open(URL, "Title", "Comma Separated Properties");

Answer (score 0):

yes there is. check it out here ... http://blog.davidkaspar.com/archives/2005/10/showmodaldialog-in-firefox-and-frames.php

or you can try this :

```
var prevReturnValue = window.returnValue; // Save the current returnValue
window.returnValue = undefined;
var dlgReturnValue = window.showModalDialog(...);
if (dlgReturnValue == undefined) // We don't know here if undefined is the real result...
{
    // So we take no chance, in case this is the Google Chrome bug
    dlgReturnValue = window.returnValue;
}
window.returnValue = prevReturnValue; // Restore the original returnValue
```

Answer (score -1):

You can search in this page $.jqDialog you will find all kind of dialog boxes you could need.
It need jquery ui

http://myprettycms.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MyPrettyCMSCommunityManager/Portals/MVC4Portal/Scripts/Views/_Layout.js

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.